# how to copy C++ enum into Objective C enum

Tags: c++, objective-c, enums

I have a C++ class having the below enum.

```
typedef enum 
{
    UnknownType = 0,
    Array = 1,
    Block = 2,  
    Enumeration = 3,
}ParameterValueType_t;
```

I want to copy this into an Objective C enum. How should I copy it

Comment: You could store the enum in a C file and use in both languages, or I think the other option should be going for Objective-C++ (naming your files as .mm)

Comment: That is a valid Objective-C enum, as Objective-C is a superset of C, so you can just copy'n'paste. But maybe that is not what you are asking?

Answer (score 1):

Use plain C to declare your enum and put it in a header file e.g. `MyEnums.h` file. Include this `MyEnums.h` in both your C++ and Objective-C files. Both languages understand the enum declaration from C.

E.g. MyEnums.h

```
#ifndef PARAMETERVALUETYPE
#define PARAMETERVALUETYPE

typedef enum {
  UnknownType = 0,
  Array = 1,
  Block = 2,
  Enumeration = 3
} ParameterValueType_t;

#endif
```

C++ File *.h/*cpp:

```
#include "MyEnums.h"

// ... C++ code
```

Objective-C File *.m:

```
#import "MyEnums.h"

// ... Objective-C code
```